# Image is not displaying from local

Tags: html

[image]I want to display the image from my local , but it is showing like this.

[image]

I don't understand what is wrong here!

The below `img` code i'm using in provider.js file

```
 <img src='../../../public/icons/videoOn.png'/>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: Can you show us the folder structure? Where's the image and where's the HTML file? How are they both related by the path?

Comment: i edited the code you can see the folder structue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the screenshot, this looks like a React JS project. For static assets, you need to import them, but only when they're inside the `src` folder. If they're inside the `public` folder, you can do this:

```
<img src='/icons/videoOn.png' />
```

The above code should work for you. If you're deploying it to a non-root and should be safer, then use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`:

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/icons/videoOn.png'} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use path as `src`, because it must be accessible via web.

Means you need `src="http://example.com/public/icons/videoOn.png"` or `src="/public/icons/videoOn.png"`

---

In that situation *always* check **Network** tab and see from where your browser tries to get file. You must be able to go to same URL and access file

Comment: Well, there's something called as relative path to the file. At the moment, the question needs more details to be answered. The URL might not be a server URL. It could even be a simple HTML file on the browser.